# How to skip mysqli empty value check?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table name `user` and 4 column name `id userid username password` where `id` is auto increment `userid`'s default value is 0 `username`'s default value is none and also `password` none.

```
id is int
userid is int
username is varchar
password is varchar
```

Now if I insert any row like

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO user SET userid='1', username='name'");
```

`Then it's showing Field`password`doesn't have a default value`

Now if I insert any row like

```
$userid = $_GET['id'];

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO user SET userid='".$userid."', username='name', password='1234'");
```

Now if the `$_GET['id'];` is empty Then it's showing `Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'userid' at row 1`

My previous server doesn't warn me like this but this is a new server and it's showing like this how can i skip this issue ?

Comment: maybe put "Null" attribute on Password column to yes?

Comment: ___Now if the $_GET['id']; is empty Then it's showing Incorrect integer value___ Well if `$_GET['id']` is empty YOU CANNOT DO THE INSERT CAN YOU, what would be the point. You should be validating that before proceeding with the INSERT

Comment: Use a ternary operator with a default value if left empty.

Comment: Check $_GET['id'] has value if not then assign 0. You can check for empty like this - if(!isset($_GET["id"])) {  $_GET['id'] = 0;}

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I get the point of that, but that would just create hundreds of user accounts with the same `userid` Surely that would just make a nonsense of the database

Comment: R'oyt ye are matey @RiggsFolly unsure what the OP wants to do here. They should be relying on their AI'd column and checking if (a) row(s) already exist. Not to mention not storing plain text passwords.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Good points, Well Made

Comment: it is pretty clear that your $_GET['id']; is not integer. if you dont want userid, dont add to your query this field!

Answer (score -2):

insert query be like

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (value1, value2, value3);
```

if you want to insert username and password field both are blank so you can editing the field in the Structure tab, look for the "NULL" checkbox. When checked, this is the equivalent of the DEFAULT NULL statement.

you can set default using query through like

set default null for username field

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `username` `username` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

set default null for password field

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `password` `password` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: Allowing `username` and `password` to be NULL makes absolutely no logical sense at all